# Regular expression to match strings composed of ABAs or ABs

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression to match all strings composed of ABAs or of ABs. Here's my regular expression right now:

(ABA)+|(AB)+

I want it to match:

```
AB
ABA
ABAB
ABAABA
ABABAB
```

But my present regular expression does not match ABAB.

If I change it to (AB)+|(ABA)+ then it does not match ABA.

How can I write a regular expression that does what I want?

What I want is a regular expression matching "the longest substring matching (AB)+ or (ABA)+".

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fG6sM1/1

Comment: Why do you need the ^ and $?

Comment: Because otherwise, you're only saying that if it finds one or more matches of AB or ABA, it is considered to be a match.  So from "ABA", it would match "AB" and call it a day.  I imagine you want the entire contents matched, not just any match.

Comment: So either it matches the entire line or it doesn't? What if I just want it to start anywhere and match the longest substrings that matches the regex?

Comment: Regex doesn't particularly care about length of a match, and as such, greedy matching won't help you (greedy matching with AB or ABA may not necessarily get you the longest results).  Alternatively you could first search using AB+ and then using ABA+, and you pick the results containing the longest match.

Comment: So maximal munch only applies for the + and * operators and not for regular expressions in general?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  Using just + and *, by default regular expressions use greedy matching, meaning that when confronted with an ambiguous choice of consuming more or passing to the next rule, it will consume.  Though this doesn't necessarily mean it will maximize results.

Comment: I *suspect* that "the longest substring matching `AB+` or `ABA+` isn't a regular language.

Comment: Is there an implementation of regular expressions that automatically tries all possible rules and returns the longest string, so as to make the OR operator maximal-munch compliant?

Comment: I whipped up a program to test this and it matches all of your strings.

Comment: @Snowman That isn't what greedy means.  Greedy is considered to be optimized because you just consume without worrying about backtracking.

Comment: @Neil I misread the comment.

Comment: In summary, this isn't possible without matching both and picking the larger match (at least not without having boundaries).  However, you shouldn't consider this such a bad thing in terms of performance, since the two newly created rules become simpler and hence easier to parse and execute.

Comment: Is there a generalized method for picking the longest match for any regex?

Answer (score -1):

You can try either `/(ABA?)+/gm` - should give you what you need.